# Is it possible to check multiple attributes without using AND or OR in mysql? If not what is the logic behind denying such action?

Tags: mysql

Please consider the following table

```
|id| first_name| last_name| nick_name|
```

What is the best way to find names that matches certain value? Following query is working but is there any better way?

```
select * from names where first_name = val OR last_name = val OR nick_name = val
```

Can i do something like -

```
select * from names where first_name OR last_name OR nick_name = val
```

If not then why mysql does not allow to perform check on multiple attributes in a single condition?

Comment: You can do `val IN(firstname,etc)`

Comment: You can not use it like in the last query as it will always result in false.

Comment: you can to `WHERE CONCAT(first_name,last_name,nicname) LIKE '%' val '%'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IN function of MySQL.

MySQL IN() function finds a match in the given arguments.

```
select * from names where val IN(first_name,last_name,nick_name);
```

This won`t work :

```
select * from names where first_name OR last_name OR nick_name = val
```

As this will always result in false condition.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73c008/1
Quick little demo that shows the problem.
When using OR between fields it's not evaluating each field against the passed in value, it's converting everything except the `nick_name` as a boolean(which it does by converting to an integer, since the names aren't numbers they're considered 0) and then ORing those results together giving it
`CAST(first_name, INTEGER) <> 0 OR CAST(last_name, INTEGER) <> 0 OR nick_name = val`